# React Native: Visible State, yet Invisible Modal (Open Modal From Dialog)

Tags: javascript, react-native, modal-dialog

This problem has been reported multiple times in the react-native repo's issues, but a bot or react native maintainer seemingly always closes the issue before it's actually resolved, which leads to the answer never being found.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal/issues/161

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19345

If you follow those links, you will see that the thread never gets to answer. In fact the issue is closed for no discernable reason. I have a problem with this because I now face the same issue and no one in the react-native team or community has been able to figure it out, probably due to the ridiculously counter-productive moderation by the react native team plus bots who are programmed to shut down productive threads for whatever reason.

Basically, I have a react native dialog that shows an animation when going from `visible={false}` to `visible={true}` and back. (`react-native-dialog` library.)

If I have a single function where I set this dialog to false and also set a modal to true `setDialogVisible(false); setModalVisible(true);`, then the modal variable will be correctly set to `true` but the modal itself:

```
<Modal visible={modalVisible}></Modal>
```

Will be invisible (even though the visible variable=`true`). Now, if I use a setTimeout function to wait until the dialog fadeout animation has resolved, the modal will appear normally after the delay. Using setTimeout in a UI function is highly prone to errors and it is extremely hacky, so using this solution is basically a terrible idea in my case I think. But, it's the only thing that works correctly as far as I know, as the Modal will never appear during a dialog fadeout animation.

Anybody have any idea how to work around this, without using a hacky timeout? Or at least more information as to why it happens?